# save file from url lua ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, url, lua

I want download mp3 file from UTL and save it to a folder.

This is my code:

```
local sound =  HTTPS.request('https://hozory.com/translate/?target='..matches[1]..'&text='..text)

local voice = json:decode(sound)

if voice.result.Voice_link ~= "false" then
local f = assert(io.open('test.mp3', 'w'))
f:write(voice.result.Voice_link)
f:close()
```

But this creates an empty mp3 file.

Comment: Try priting `voice.result.Voice_link`. What is it displayed?

Comment: Try using `'wb'` instead of `'w'`.